# What is the best apporach to enable the end-user maintain static data in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm using `JasperReports` for reporting purposes with `JasperServer`. There is a database in place and it is configured in `JasperReports` as a datasource. Reports use sql queries to get the data for reports.

There are some tables in the database with static data like lookup tables for translating ID's in labels or tables which represents the organizational structure. Most of these tables are used in the "input controls" on the `JasperServer`.

The challenge is to enable the end-user to change these tables in production without the developer.
What is the best approach to solve this problem?

The version of the `JasperReports` is 4.5.0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Jasper" is Tomcat's JSP engine. It's not related to JasperReports.

Comment: The solution I'he choosed was to use the functionality of the oracle db to create a table that is linked to an csv file. This File will be copied with sftp to the defined directory on the db server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach would be to not use jasper-reports or jasperserver to accomplish this. Either develop your own 'query manager' software or use an open source / off the shelf version. For something this simple it would be relatively easy to roll your own simple table editor and then integrate it into your jasperserver site.